# redirect all incoming e-mail on domain to one specific e-mail address

Tags: email, dns, gmail, google-apps, mx-record

redirect all incoming e-mail on domain to one specific e-mail address

I have a domain: `example.com`
and one e-mail: `info@example.com`

i would like to receive all e-mail what it got in my domain:
`example@example.com`
`nospam@example.com`
`asdasdasd@example.com`
`[any random character]@example.com`

I don`t want to create these e-mails one by one.

I`am using gmail (`apps.google.com`)

btw: my main goal to have different e-mail for different website and `example+slug@example.com` trick is not working because lots of website filter `+` letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you. Don't create the accounts, just set the catchall

```
https://support.google.com/a/answer/33962?hl=en
```

Comment: thank you, google need 1 hour to make it work